# is there a way can use delegate to ejecute a method in a viewController from other ViewController?

Tags: swift

i have two viewControllers, well i have a viewController and inside viewController i have a viewContainer that obviusly is a viewController too.

the thing is that i want that when user clicks on a button in the viewController(container view) run a method a method of the other viewController.

i have the next code in the viewController (containerView)

```
protocol ubicacionContainerViewControllerDelegate {
  func cambiarContainer(posicion : Int)
}

class ubicacionContainerViewController: UIViewController {
var delegate :ubicacionContainerViewControllerDelegate? 

  //i am using tables is for that reason i have this code but when the user select a
  // row i want to run a other method in other viewController

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let celda_seleccionada = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as!
    celdaUbicacionContainerTableViewCell

    ReservaViewController.reserVaServicio.lugar = "\(celda_seleccionada.lbPais) en \ 
   (celda_seleccionada.lbCiudad) "

    delegate?.cambiarContainer(posicion: 5)

}
```

now in the other viewController i have the follow code:

```
class ReservaViewController: UIViewController,ubicacionContainerViewControllerDelegate {

func cambiarContainer(posicion: Int) {
    //self.posicion = posicion

    if(posicion == 5){
        print(posicion)
    }

}
```

now how do i say to ReservaViewController that is delegado of the other viewController or how can i do it? using delegate i runned it but  the method cambiarContainer does not run

Answer (score 0):

In your ubicacionContainerViewController you can write this code on your didSelect:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let nextView = UIStoryboard.viewController(name: "Storyboard Name",identifier: "Storyboard Identifier") as! ReservaViewController 

nextView.valueInt = 5

self.present(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

while in your ReservaViewController you can declare a variable int

var valueInt = Int!

in there you can create your own method:

```
func setupMethod() {

if valueInt == 5 {

print(valueInt)

} else {

print(valueInt)

}

}
```

Comment: Type 'UIStoryboard' has no member 'viewController'    i have that error.

Comment: Hi David can you try this in your ubicacionContainerViewController in your didSelectRowAt

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard Name", bundle: nil)
                
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storyboard Identifier") as! ViewControllerNotification
                
 self.present(vc, animated: true)